# MCP6548 comparator circuit isn't working

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator

Hey guys back at it again, sorry.

I am using a standard [MCP6548](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21714G.pdf) Comparator to finish the first stage of my project.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgotgU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*OP's schematic.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy1rZI.png)</sup>

*A little tidy-up to separate the rectifier and comparator functions, run R4 downwards to GND and clean up the power supply. Section labels don't hurt either. [Transistor]*

The probem is the comparator isn't working. When - > +, it is not staying at GND. When the input signal CH1 is Higher than CH2 it should stay at GND. Yes the output of the OPA350 is solid and working as it should.

Comment: The first two words in the datasheet say "open drain", are you familiar with the term?

Comment: I am not sorry:/, honestly first time using a comparator so I am pretty sure its operator error

Comment: When the input signal is positive with respect to ground, where does the current go (if any is present?) How does any current sink?

Comment: oyy, kinda embarrassing for me but I have no idea. Really rusty when it comes to these type of things. I would assume @jonk It goes back to the VSS? through ground

Comment: AHHH, I see I remember now it requires a pull up resistor from output to VCC to output high.

Comment: Weird, its still shooting to VDD when - > + ?

Comment: @Pllsz You need a way for the (-) input of your 1st (CMOS) stage to be at a virtual ground. If the input is positive, then (in theory) the (-) input should be at virtual ground and the current entering that node should also be exiting via R2. That supposed R2 current goes where, exactly?

Comment: I see what you mean, I added a resistor to the negative rail of the MCP6548, cause at the positive input of the first stage the current will follow into the second stage input, however it didnt fix anything :/ When - > + it still shoots up to VDD.

Comment: @Pllsz That's actually not very helpful. Look more closely. You have a (+) signal source for a moment, the (-) OPA350 terminal should be at ground (virtual), and therefore there should be current flowing OUT through R2. To do that, the (-) MCP6548 terminal has to be NEGATIVE with respect to ground. How does your newly added resistor achieve this?

Comment: Yeah, I really dont know. This is my first time working with OP AMPS, I believe Ill just frustrate you more. I understand that when the input is positive yes current will be leaving the output of the first stage, however and will then split between to R2 and the second stage. I believe when you add the resistor it will shunt the current away from the second stage.

Comment: I got everything working, the pull up fixed everything, and I somehow changed my voltage divider branch and that's why it didnt go to ground. @jonk Thank you for everything !

Comment: @Pllsz Great to hear! Best wishes!

Comment: @Plisz `I somehow changed my voltage divider branch and that's why it didn't go to ground`. How did you change it?

Comment: @Unknown123 By changing the value of one of the voltage divider resistors while keeping the other constant.

Comment: There should be bypass capacitors on the power supply.

Answer (score 0):

I’m glad to see you got your first circuit working.

Just a little note.

First rail to rail Op Amp is a negative input wave “inverting precision peak detector” that produces a positive output at x1 gain.

Since the comparator only detects  inputs greater than the reference voltage so the negative peak detector is somewhat unnecessary if you expect positive input peaks to be symmetrical.

Thus you can go directly into the comparator.